# Python invalid value encountered in log

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Доброго времени суток.

Сегодня пришла идея навесить ограничения на свою формулу отрисовки графика, но столкнулся с проблемой:

> RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in log y =
> numpy.log(numpy.log(c*x+d)/numpy.log(b))/numpy.log(a)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотя график отрисовывается, как на мой взгляд правильно.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мой код на Python

```
import matplotlib.pyplot
import numpy
import math
import csv

with open("test.tsv") as tsvfile: # безопасное открытие файла (выполнится в любом случае и закроется файл)
    tsvreader = csv.reader(tsvfile, delimiter="\t")
    data =[list(map(int, row)) for row in tsvreader]
 
x = numpy.arange(-10.0, 10.1, 0.01) # задаются параметры интервала с шагом
for a, b, c, d in data:
    y = numpy.log(numpy.log(c*x+d)/numpy.log(b))/numpy.log(a)
    matplotlib.pyplot.plot(x, y, label = f'a = {a}, b = {b}, c = {c}, d = {d}') # функция создания графика
 
matplotlib.pyplot.xlabel(r'Ось OX',fontsize = '14' ,color = 'r') # устанавливает подпись оси х
matplotlib.pyplot.ylabel(r'Ось OY',fontsize = '14' , color = 'b') # устанавливает подпись оси у
matplotlib.pyplot.title(r'$y = log_alog_b(cx+d)$' ,fontsize = '14' , color = 'g')
matplotlib.pyplot.legend() # добавление легенды
matplotlib.pyplot.show() # отображение окна с графиком
```

Вот моя функция
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

Эта ошибка возникает если передать `np.log(arg)` отрицательное значение в качестве аргумента.

И действительно, трудно придумать такое число `x` при возведении `np.e` (2.71828) в которое (2.71828<sup>x</sup>) мы бы получили **отрицательное число**!

Воспроизведение ошибки:

```
In [48]: np.log(-1)
/opt/anaconda3/envs/ml/bin/ipython:1: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in log
Out[48]: nan
```

Comment: `И действительно, трудно придумать` - это плохой аргумент. У функции есть `область определения` И если даже вы с Алексом придумаете :) , это вам не поможет

Comment: @splash58, пытался писать максимально доступным языком ;) PS про область определения функции я в курсе...

Comment: про последнее я совсем не сомневаюсь :) Просто, он так же и преподу скажет

Comment: Я добавил проверку, специально сделал аргумент b отрицательным, но что-то сообщение не хочет выдавать, подскажите что не так.
`
x = numpy.arange(0.1, 10.1, 0.01) # задаются параметры интервала с шагом
for a, b, c, d in data:
    if numpy.all(c*x+d <= 0) or numpy.all(b) <= 0 or numpy.all(a) <= 0:
        print ("Передача отрицательных параметров невозможна")
    else:
        y = numpy.log(numpy.log(c*x+d)/numpy.log(b))/numpy.log(a)
        matplotlib.pyplot.plot(x, y, label = f'a = {a}, b = {b}, c = {c}, d = {d}') # функция создания графика
`

Comment: @Alex, у вас проверка на то, что ВСЕ элементы неположительные - замените `.all()` на `.any()`)

Comment: Заменил всё на .any , но print ("Передача отрицательных параметров невозможна") так и не увидел при b = -3

Comment: Это я затупил. извините.
Надо было просто операторы сравнения перенести в _np.any\all()_

if numpy.any(c*x+d <= 0) or numpy.any(b <= 0) or numpy.any(a <= 0):